# Google Chrome no me reproduce radio

Tags: html, google-chrome, stream

Tengo una web con una radio que coge el sonido via stream, lo coge por: http://178.156.37.238:8888/stream . Al probar en local Google Chrome me lo reproduce perfectamente y al publicarlo no reproduce.

```
                    <a href="#banner" class="button style2 scrolly-middle">
                    <audio
                    controls
                    src="http://178.156.37.238:8888/stream">
                        Your browser does not support the
                        <code>audio</code> element.
                </audio>
                    </a>
```

La web está publica https://radiohumorfm.com/ , se reproduce en firefox, en safari y en dispositivos moviles perfectamente pero en Google chrome no se escucha y me parece en en Edge tampoco, estoy buscando la solución pero no he encontrado nada, no se si es porque el sonido lo coge de una ruta sin *https*

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de este modo:

```
<audio controls autoplay="true">
   <source src="http://178.156.37.238:8888/stream" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Aunque intenté con tu código y me funcionó perfectamente. Uso Edge

Comment: Gracias, el problema que no lo he comentado y tengo que agregarlo es que en local google chrome si me lo reproduce y cuando lo subo a la web no.

Comment: Si probas agregando un video en vez de un audio para ver si te lo reproduce?  Para descartar problemas en el codigo

Comment: Lo he probado y tampoco.